# How to make Vigenere cipher with upper/lower case letters and numbers

Tags: c#, vigenere

I need to do vigenere cipher which can encrypt words with lower/upper case letters and numbers. I'm new to c# so I don't really know how to do it. Tried to edit this code, but could'nt do much.

```
class VCipher
        {
            public string encrypt(string txt, string pw, int d)
            {
                int pwi = 0, tmp;
                string ns = "";
                txt = txt.ToUpper();
                pw = pw.ToUpper();
                foreach (char t in txt)
                {
                    if (t < 65) continue;
                    tmp = t - 65 + d * (pw[pwi] - 65);
                    if (tmp < 0) tmp += 26;
                    ns += Convert.ToChar(65 + (tmp % 26));
                    if (++pwi == pw.Length) pwi = 0;
                }

                return ns;
            }
        };
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what your issue is? What's wrong with sample code above? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The code only encrypts and decrypts only word with letters within them, I need to encrypt words with numbers and other symbols